# How does the "net view" command work?

Tags: cmd.exe

I believe the command send some kind of broadcast message to all the hosts in its current network, and then those hosts replied?

Given that it returns the domain names, so does it queries the DNS as well after gaining the IP address from those replies?

*Excuse me if the question is explained elsewhere. I did searched it for a while and most entries are troubleshooting regarding the command where its not working, but none actually explain the mechanism.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `net view` only uses NetBIOS and nothing else.

If WINS is not available (which it almost never is), then the list of computers
is retrieved from the "master browser", which is found via NetBIOS over TCP/IP
broadcasts.

The command will only find computers whose network discovery is turned on.

For more info see
[The Browse Service](http://ubiqx.org/cifs/Browsing.html).